# Remove DOM element from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to push in my array some Dom elements, and sometimes, to remove then from the array.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
var myDOMS = new Array();
myDOMS.push($("#myDiv"));

var element_to_remove = $("#myDiv");
var index = $.inArray(element_to_remove, myDOMS);
if (index > -1) {
  myDOMS.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The part about removing doesn't work. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Is it possible?

Comment: What you're doing is possible, you can match elements by their id, however this seems like an X/Y question, as I'm not sure why you want to do this, but I am almost certain there's a better way to achieve what you need.

Comment: removing element from array won't remove it from DOM just to point that out

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Actually I wrote `$("#myDiv")` but it could be `$(".myDiv")`..

Comment: @sumeetkumar Yes I know, thank you, I just want to remove it from the array

Comment: You're trying to match jQuery objects by reference; that's not going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you evaluate `$("#myDiv")` you will get a new object back. So this is *never* true:

```
$("#myDiv") === $("#myDiv")
```

If you want to work like this, you should really use the DOM element references. Something like this:

```
var myDOMS = new Array();
myDOMS.push($("#myDiv").get(0));

var element_to_remove = $("#myDiv").get(0);
var index = $.inArray(element_to_remove, myDOMS);
console.log(index);
if (index > -1) {
  myDOMS.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a correction.

- you are not talking about DOM, you are talking about jQuery collections. @trincot mentioned this. `$(XYZ)` gets you a new object that contains a collection of all DOM elements matched by the selector (the `XYZ` part).

with that, here is the solution without jQuery complications:

```js
var elements = []; //prefer literal constructor over "new Array();" for brevity
elements.push(document.getElementById("myDiv"));

var element_to_remove = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var index =  elements.indexOf(element_to_remove);

console.log("element index: "+index);

if(index !== -1){
   //element was present in the array
   elements.splice(index,1);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue that you are having is that when you use a jQuery selector, you create a unique jQuery object (or collection of objects, if there is more than one), that contains a bunch of information about the matching element, including a reference to the DOM element itself (the first bit of information, referenceable by `$("#someElement")[0]`

Since these objects are unique, while they may contain identical information about the returned element, the objects themselves are not equal. So, for:

```
var bodyRef1 = $("body");
var bodyRef2 = $("body");
var bodyRef3 = $("body");
```

You will find that the values contained in the object are all equal:

```
bodyRef1[0] === bodyRef2[0] === bodyRef3[0]
bodyRef1.context === bodyRef2.context === bodyRef3.context
etc. . . .
```

The objects themselves are not

```
bodyRef1 !== bodyRef2 !== bodyRef3
```

In your case, unless there is a specific reason why you need to have the elements selected in a jQuery format, you might actually be better off simply doing a native JavaScript selection, and remove the extra layer of complexity:

```
var myDOMS = new Array();
myDOMS.push(document.getElementById("myDiv"));

var element_to_remove = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var index = $.inArray(element_to_remove, myDOMS);
if (index > -1) {
  myDOMS.splice(index, 1);
}
```

This works because the native JS selection returns only a reference to the DOM element.